# Splitting ASCII text files in C

Tags: c, file, split, fopen

Suppose I have the following code in C:

```
FILE* a=fopen("myfile.txt","r");
FILE* b,c;
```

There is a delimiter line in 'a', which designates the place where I want to split; and I want to split the contents of 'a' into 'b',and 'c'. I want to do this without creating any other files.

Also later, I want to do this dynamically, by creating a pointer array pointing to 'FILE*'s. So the number of delimiter lines will be arbitrary.

For this case, suppose that the delimiter line is any line that has the string 'delim'.

Comment: Nothing, since I have very little idea. I may guess that a FILE* can be addressed like a char* and manipulated like a string.

Comment: Can I fprintf to a FILE* without fopening it?

Comment: No, a `(FILE *)` is not a string and cannot be manipulated like one, and a file must be opened to be operated on.  (Actually it sounds like you are thinking of `mmap`, but haven't thought it though.)

Comment: Why do you want to use C for this?  It's a perfectly horrible language for this task.

Comment: I am using a huge single-file library for triangulation. Also, I realized that I can bypass this option by parsing the file myself. Here is the link: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/triangle.html

Comment: BLUEPIXY, you're right, there goes the fundamental flaw of my mnemonics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept could be:

1) `fopen()` INFILE and (first) OUTFILE

2) while you can, `fgets()` lines from INFILE and `strncmp()` them to the delimiter

2.a) delimiter not found: `fputs()` the line to OUTFILE

2.b) delimiter found: `fclose()` OUTFILE and `fopen()` the next OUTFILE

2.c) end of file: break loop

3) `fclose()` INFILE and OUTFILE

Or this way:

1) `fopen()`INFILE

2) `fseek()` to the end of the stream and use `ftell()` to get the file position, let's call this `N`

3) `rewind()` the stream and `fread()` `N` bytes from it into a buffer.

4) `fclose()`INFILE

5) while you can, `strstr()` the delimiter in your buffer and `fwrite()` the data blocks inbetween to OUTFILEs

Comment: Would I be able to do this without creating any other files? Thanks.

Comment: Without creating temporary files? Yes.